# CentOS 7 - Systemctl dependency problems with network mount and OpenSM

Tags: centos, mount, glusterfs, systemd, infiniband

I have the follwoing problem. I want to mount a glusterfs share over Infiniband on an CentOS 7 client. The glusterfs share '/data' is severed by a host called storage1. For the client I  I setup and minimal CentOS system. I installed `rdma` and `opensm` to get the infiniband up running. Both are added to the boot sequence via

```
systemctl enable rdma.service 
systemctl enable opensm.service
```

The network devices are managed using NetworkManager and `ping storage1` works fine over the infiniband network. Then I added, as described in the gluster documentation an fstab entry:

```
storage1:/data   /net/data glusterfs       defaults,acl,_netdev    0       0
```

When I now restarted the system the `net-data.mount` service failed. After the booting is finished I can log in and start I manually:

```
systemctl start net-data.mount
```

and everything works fine. After analyzing the problem I found out that all other network shares (nfs, gluster) that use the normal ethernet connection of the client are mounted during boot. In the `journalctl` I found out that OpenSM, which is necessary for Inifiniband, is too slow during startup. The mount of the above mentioned shared is performend 5 seconds before OpenSM finishes its startup. But the service description of OpenSM says that it is wanted by the `network.target` and so it is stared before the network shares are mounted.

So my question is how I can either introduce a sleep timer somewhere in the boot sequence which waits until the Inifiniband network is really ready/OpenSM is reading.

I do not use the RDMA features of gluster.

The OpenSM service file is, as installed by yum/rpm:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the OpenSM InfiniBand fabric Subnet Manager
Documentation=man:opensm
DefaultDependencies=false
Before=network.target remote-fs-pre.target
Requires=rdma.service
After=rdma.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/opensm-launch

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

**Edit:**
I found a workround which seems to a really bad one. I edited the /usr/libexec/opensm-launch and append sleep 15 at its and to systemd waits until the launch-script is finished.

Is it possible to integrate such behavior in systemd?

Comment: please can you provide the service file?

Comment: I added it above, it is the one install by yum.

Comment: I found a workround which seems to a really bad one. I edited the `/usr/libexec/opensm-launch` and append `sleep 15` at its and to systemd waits until the launch-script is finished.

Comment: This whole thing is a mess. They really need to get rid of the opensm-launch script entirely and integrate it into systemd properly.